# Установить иконку в TabHost Андроид

Tags: android

Всем привет. Поставил TabHost

```
<TabHost
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tabHost">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ListView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/listView" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">
            </LinearLayout>

        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Потом инициализирую в классе.

```
TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
tabHost.setup();

TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec;
// создаем вкладку и указываем тег
tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tag1");
// название вкладки
tabSpec.setIndicator("Альбомы");
// указываем id компонента из FrameLayout, он и станет содержимым
tabSpec.setContent(R.id.tab1);
// добавляем в корневой элемент
tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);


tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tag2");
// название вкладки
// указываем id компонента из FrameLayout, он и станет содержимым
tabSpec.setContent(R.id.tab2);
// добавляем в корневой элемент
tabSpec.setIndicator("Песни", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.song_icon));
tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
```

В этой строчке я устанавливаю иконку на вкладку:

```
tabSpec.setIndicator("Песни", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.song_icon));
```

но она не показывается. Что может быть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я делал так:

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_icon, mTabHost.getTabWidget(), false);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.tab_icon_home);
        TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec = mTabHost.newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(view);
        mTabHost.addTab(tabSpec, fragmentClass, null);
```

где `tab_icon`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/tab_height"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#EEE"
    android:foreground="@drawable/tab_icon_bg">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/tab_icon_home"
        android:scaleType="centerInside" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Ну да я посмотрел что есть конструктор и с view, но блин почему нифига неработает с draweble

Comment: Как тут пишут http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10745092/icon-in-tab-is-not-showing-up/11379708#11379708, в API14+ на смартфонах иконка вместе с текстом не отображается. Похоже что это by design. Так что только кастомный индикатор.

Comment: У меня возникло 2 вопроса по Вашему решению: 1) Зачем нам два изображения - на foreground и scr? 2) Все Linear Layout были убраны из Frame layout. А что если вкладок несколько?